# Laravel 6.5 register redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel 6.5 still new to PHP and Laravel. When I register successfully, it returns me back to the same registration form with its inputs empty, it successfully registers the user, tho, but won't redirect. I've tried overriding the redirectPath() function as well which isn't working.

When i tried overriding other methods (such as ShowRegistrationForm() ) it worked perfectly, but I can't get it to redirect.

The redirect works perfectly for the login controller.

Here is my RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }

    /** Overrriding native method */
    public function showRegistrationForm(){

        $this->authorize('register', User::class);
        return view('auth.register');

    }


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ]);
        return redirect()->to($this->redirectTo);
    }
}
```

and web.php with my route

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

/** Since we can't register without login in. I'll try to do the 'registering' by myself. */
Route::post('/users', 'HomeController@store');

/** In here we will try and do all 7 resource methods in one line of code */
Route::resource('trabajos', 'TrabajoController');

/** Ruta para que el admin vea todos los trabajos de los usuarios */
Route::get('/usuarios', 'AdminController@index');
/** Ruta para eliminar alguno */
Route::delete('usuarios/{usuario}', 'AdminController@delete')->name('admin.delete');

Route::get('/usuarios/{usuario}', 'AdminController@show');

/** Tratando de setear el Price de un trabajo específico */
Route::post('/setPrice/{trabajoId}', 'AdminController@setPrice');

/** Updateando información de trabajos de otros usuarios */
Route::get('/usuarios/{usuario}/trabajo/{trabajo}/edit', 'AdminController@editJob');
/** Patching it */
Route::patch('/usuarios/{usuario}/trabajo/{trabajo}', 'AdminController@updateJob');

/** Filtering */
Route::get('/usuarios/{usuario}/filtro', 'AdminController@filter');

/** Getting a pdf */
Route::get('/usuarios/{usuario}/pdf','AdminController@export_pdf');
```

and my homeController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    /** From here and down, it's mine  */
    public function store(){

        $data=request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
        ]);
        /* User::create($data); */
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = request()->name;
        $user->email = request()->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt(request()->password);

        $user->save();

        return back();

    }
}
```

Comment: `$redirectTo` I think should be `$this->redirecTo`, however it may also be you're blocking the header that does the redirect because there's already been output to the buffer.

Comment: Already tried modifying `$redirectTo` like `$this->redirectTo`, as the second answer reccommended (I should and will edit my question there), but it still doesn't work.

I don't understand, tho, what you mean by 'blocking the header that does the redirect because there's already been output to the buffer'. Could you please explain further or reccommend me what to do if it's the case?

Comment: Essentially, http is a series of headers followed by a content body. Once you start "outputting to the content buffer" (or body, there's a default stream), you can no longer send headers, since it's a stream. Any kind of dumping a value or even a stray whitespace can cause a header not to be added. You do need the `$this->redirectTo` (or just `return redirecto('/home');`), you just haven't found the other issue(s) yet.

Comment: Read this for more info on headers and outputting: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I understood (partially) your explanation. I think It might be related to the fact that, because of the app's requirements, I must be already logged in when doing the registration. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Show your routes, please?

Comment: @Dmitry, I edited my question in order to add my web.php with my routes.

Comment: Show your home Controller action store, please.

Comment: Please try to insert {{ $errors }} in your register form.

Comment: And let me show your register blade.

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks a lot, pal. It had been some time since I had modified this Laravel app for the last time, and I had totally forgotten about checking HomeController@store. I feel like a retard.

I'll edit my question to add homeController just so you can see how BLIND i was and  If you wish you can create a new answer down below pointing me to change my HomeController@store (instead of in a comment), so I can select it as best answer, and thanks again.

Comment: @Dmitry, else I would select your previous answer as best one, cause you were the one that truly helped me solve this stupid issue.
Anyways I wouldn't like to do that because that wasn't actually the answer for the question, and it could be missguiding to other people who happen to watch this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In action store change `back()` to `redirect() - >route('home')`. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

after successful registration – you get redirected where? To default /home URL, or whatever is specified in $redirectTo property in RegisterController.
So, how to customize it and make Laravel “remember” the previous page for registration, too?
So you should override register method in RegisterController, for doing this you can copy the register method that is in this location 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php
and change it like this in your RegisterController.

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: After a successfull registration I don't get redirected anywhere; it just reloads the current view with the registration form with it's inputs cleared.

Tried adding your code to try to override register method, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect on register action, not create action

Here is my RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:web');

    }

    /** Overrriding native method */
    public function showRegistrationForm(){
        return view('auth.register');
    }


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
       return  User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ]);

    }

   public function register(Request $request)
   {
      $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

      event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

      $this->guard()->login($user);

      return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
   }

}
```